# Flutter - Cómo cambiar el tamaño de una página

Tags: flutter, dart

Quisiera cambiar el tamaño de este widget (página), muchas gracias.!!!

```
 Widget _mainContainer() {
 return new Container(
    child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Center(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
            _formContainer(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
 }
```

Se trata de un page en el cual debo implementar muchas cosas, pero idealmente que tenga un tamaño inferior.

Este es el widget principal:

> Cita en bloque

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
    key: globalKey,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[_mainContainer(), progressDialogRegion],
    ));
```

}

Comment: Puedes agregar tu widget principal? lo que has puesto en la pregunta, es un método que te retorna un widget,  quieres reducir el tamaño de ese widget? o de tu widget principal (stateless o stateful ) , agrega más código y describe con claridad el problema

Comment: Ya agregué el widget principal, en donde se llama al método _mainContainer, gracias.!

Comment: Ok, quieres reducir el widget principal o que? Puedes agregad un screeshot de como se ve actualmente y como desees que quede?

Comment: Lo que quiero es reducir el tamaño del widget principal. Voy en camino a mi trabajo y no puedo agregar los screenshots por ahora... Graciasssss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es simplemente usar el widget `SizedBox` para definir el tamaño , pero recuerda que se verá un fondo negro en la parte de atrás.

```
return Center(child: 
        SizedBox( 
        height: 200,
        width: 200, 
        child: Scaffold(
    key: globalKey,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[_mainContainer(), progressDialogRegion],
    ))));
```

Si lo que buscas es usar ventanas tipo `Dialog`, puedes hacerlo simplemente usando `showDialog` y pasando el widget con el tamaño predefinido, ejemplo:

```
showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (_) => MyDialogPage(),
                          );
```

```
class MyDialogPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          height: 300,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text("Hello world"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: He visto widgets de tamaño un poco inferior al page previo y con una x en el extremo para cerrarla...los conoces??

Comment: si, para ese caso necesitas usar `showDialog`